# error while executing Update query in the asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I have used a class in which i have this update query for Payment Fees of a student whose Unique ID is UID and an Account ID is used for him i.e. AccId

```
public string updatePays(string UID,int AccId,float hostel,float book,float exam,float reval,float studentDevelop,float misc,float reregistration,float late,float dues,float arrear,float grandtotal)
    {
        string SQLQuery = " UPDATE Pays SET ExamFees = " + exam + ",ReValuationFees = " + reval + ",Hostelfees = " + hostel + ",BookFees = " + book + ",StudentDevelopFees = " + studentDevelop + ",ReregistrationFees = " + reregistration + ",MiscFees = " + misc + ",LateFees=" + late + ",DuesFees=" + dues + ",Backfees=" + arrear + ",GrandFees=" + grandtotal + " WHERE UID = '" + UID + "' AND AccId = " + AccId + "";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQLQuery, sqlConnection);
        string flag = "";

        sqlConnection.Open();
        try
        {
            flag = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            if (flag.ToString() != null)
            {
                sqlConnection.Close();
                return flag;
            }
            else
            {
                sqlConnection.Close();
                return "Student Fees has not been Updated ";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exr)
        {
            sqlConnection.Close();
            return exr.Message;
        }
    }
```

Now I call this function from a button click event

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DatabaseLayer data = new DatabaseLayer();

        string UID = Session["UID"].ToString();
        int AccId = AccId = (int)(Session["Acc"]);
        string semfees = Session["semFees"].ToString();

        float hostel = 0;
        float book = 0;
        float exam = 0;
        float reval = 0;
        float studentDevelop = 0;
        float misc = 0;
        float reregistration = 0;
        float late = 0;
        float dues = 0;
        float arrear = 0;
        float grandtotal = 0;
        float sf = float.Parse(semfees.ToString());

        if (float.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, out hostel)) { }
        if (float.TryParse(TextBox3.Text, out book)) { }
        if (float.TryParse(TextBox4.Text, out exam)) { }
        if (float.TryParse(TextBox5.Text, out reval)) { }
        if (float.TryParse(TextBox12.Text, out studentDevelop)) { }
        if (float.TryParse(TextBox6.Text, out misc)) { }
        if (float.TryParse(TextBox7.Text, out reregistration)) { }
        if (float.TryParse(TextBox8.Text, out late)) { }
        if (float.TryParse(TextBox9.Text, out dues)) { }
        if (float.TryParse(TextBox10.Text, out arrear)) { }

        string flag = "";

        grandtotal = sf + hostel + book + exam + reval + studentDevelop + misc + reregistration + late + dues + arrear;

        flag = data.updatePays(UID, AccId, hostel, book, exam, reval, studentDevelop, misc, reregistration, late, dues, arrear, grandtotal);
        Literal1.Text = flag.ToString();
    }
```

I am getting eror saying

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

**This error was shown in the literal1**

Can any one tell where am i going wrong? I mean i saw to it that all the delcaration is done properly

Now after using (ctr+Alt+E) it gave error at

```
flag = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

> saying **NullReferenceException occured**

Comment: Where does this exception get thrown?  Enable stop-on-exceptions (Ctrl+Alt+E in VS.Net - check the relevant box to stop on framework exceptions).

Comment: _Where_ do you get that error?

Comment: @Will A I did follow (Ctrl+Alt+E) and it gave error at 

flag = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); 

saying NullReferenceException occured

Comment: `flag.ToString() != null` is also wrong : if ToString() can't be null and if flag is null is would throw an Exception

Comment: @Julien N i am getting exaception for a student who already has a payment under his/her UID... So it cant be null atleast for the update for UID which has a payment ..  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a potential problem:

```
  flag = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

If ExecuteScalar() returns null then your ToString() will throw the null-ref exception.

Edit: since it seems to be this line, rewrite it as:

```
object tmp command.ExecuteScalar();
flag = tmp.ToString();
```

And use the debugger to see if tmp is null.

#### Edit2:

And it probably will be NULL. An **`UPDATE ...`** sql statement should be executed with **`ExecuteNonQuery`**, not with **`ExecuteScalar`**.

Comment: Although you're correct that it'd cause an error, it's in a try catch, so it wouldn't cause the OP's error.

Comment: but i got error for an existing UID, which means ExecuteScalar() should return a value!!?

Comment: I had even used int flag = command.ExecuteNonQuery() which just returned from the function ..

Comment: if want to use a select sql statement and retrieve a value , I still got NullRefrenceException, Do you feel i should use more often either Execute reader for select query?

Comment: Yes, the only way to get records back is to use ExecuteReader(). ExecuteScalar() is for `SELECT MAX()` kind of queries.